# How to acess the length of a find() result in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

## THE ANSWER TO THIS QUESTION AND THIS WHOLE QUESTION IS OBSOLETE. EMBER DATA HAS CHANGED A LOT. READ THIS: http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.11.0/models/

I have this little Ember application:

```js
window.App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  revision: 11,
  adapter: DS.FixtureAdapter({
    simulateRemoteResponse: false
  })
});

App.Model = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string')
});
App.Model.FIXTURES = [];

App.ready = function() {
  console.dir(App.Model.find().get('length'));
  App.Model.createRecord({id: 1, title: "TEST"});
  console.dir(App.Model.find().get('length'));
  console.dir(App.Model.find(1).get('title'));
};
```

I get the right title in `console.dir(App.Model.find(1).get('title')` however both of the `get('length')` calls return 0. What am I missing?

Here is a (non-) working jsbin: http://jsbin.com/uxalap/6/edit

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason might be that you are invoking `get("length")` even before the data has been loaded,

Basically when you do `App.Model.find()` it returns you an instance of `RecordArray` but it wont have data, in the background it queries with the database and will fetch the data, now once the data is loaded you'll find the actual length

you might try adding an Observer on `isLoaded` property as follows

```
record = App.store.findQuery(App.Model);
alertCount = function(){
  if(record.isLoaded){
    alert(record.get("length"));
  }
};
Ember.addObserver("isLoaded", record, alertCount);
```

Comment: You can also use the 'didLoad' event instead of indirect property observation: record.one('didLoad', function(){ alert(record.get('length')) });

Comment: @ChristopherSwasey now I get : Error: Not Found
    at RSVP.onerrorDefault

Comment: This QA is 2 years old and Ember Data has changed significantly in that time. I wish there were a way to flag and obsolete questions/answers on SO.

Comment: @ChristopherSwasey thats true. I added a note to the question.